# Why one variable can not be read after swaping two variables

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, sizeof, strcpy

In the output, there is only water is printed, but no soda is printed. But in my opinion, soda has less size, it should be easily saved in x because x has a bigger size. If I set y who has more chars than x, then it doesn't have such a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char x[] = "water";
  char y[] = "soda";
  char temp[10];

  strcpy(temp, x);
  strcpy(x, y);
  strcpy(y, temp);

  printf("%s", x);
  printf("%s", y);
  printf("%d", sizeof(x));
  printf("%d", sizeof(y));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code invokes undefined behavior because the size of the array `y` (equal to `5`) is less than the size of the array `x` (equal to `6`). So you may not copy the array `x` into the array `y` using the function `strcpy`.

You could declare the array `y` for example the following way

```
char x[] = "water";
char y[sizeof( x )] = "soda";
```

Pay attention to that the array sizes are not changed. They have compile-time values because the declared arrays are not variable length arrays. It seems you wanted to compare lengths of the stored strings using the function `strlen` as for example

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen(x));
printf("%zu\n", strlen(y));
```

Also the both the operator `sizeof` and the function `strlen` yield values of the type `size_t`. So you have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%d` in calls of `printf` as for example

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(x));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(y));
```

Comment: But actually, i can copy x into y, but not y into x. do u know the reason

Comment: @Elias As I wrote copying x in the array y invokes undefined behavior because the memory beyond the array y will be overwritten. The array y contains only 5 elements but you are copying 6 elements from the array x.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but I'll add that the way to fix is to specify the size of the arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char x[6] = "water";
  char y[6] = "soda";
  char temp[6];

  strcpy(temp, x);
  strcpy(x, y);
  strcpy(y, temp);

  printf("%s", x);
  printf("%s", y);
  printf("%d", sizeof(x));
  printf("%d", sizeof(y));
  return 0;
```

Comment: do u know the reason

Comment: `printf("%d", sizeof(x))` leads to undefined behavior. Conversion specifiers are required to match their arguments, and the appropriate conversion specifier for `size_t` (the type yielded by the `sizeof` operator) is `%zu` Also, `char x[6] = ...` could simply be `char x[] = ...`, but this hardcoding of array dimensions to suit imagined operations is probably not the right solution except for limited toy examples.